# Register Global Hotkey in Windows CE

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, windows-ce

i search for a method to register for a global hotkey, so i can trigger a method when the key gets pressed.

It needs to work with Windows CE and Windows Mobile >=5.

[EDIT: It also needs to work when the application is hidden and/or the form has no focus]

Comment: I find it strange that `RegisterHotkey` doesn't work. It is designed for global hotkeys which work when your application doesn't have focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If RegisterHotKey fails to do what you want for some reason, put in a [keyboard hook](http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2009/12/04/hooking-the-keyboard-message-queue-in-compact-framework-code/).  Hooks aren't "officially" supported, but for the keyboard they work just fine.

Comment: I'd avoid this if `RegisterHotkey` works. This is only a last resort if you can't use `RegisterHotkey` for some reason. If this were a Desktop application I'd downvote, but I don't know enough about WinCE to know if it might be necessary there.

Comment: Absolutely, he should try RegisterHotKey.  Not sure what your primal aversion to SetWindowsHook is, but having developed for Windows CE devices for over a decade, I know which route I'd go.

Comment: The problem with a low level keyboard hook is that all keyboard input needs to go through it and can be delayed by your thread not responding quickly. One example where this totally bit me was a game which stupidly used high priority and starved another program which had a low level keyboard hook. This resulted in multiple seconds input lag. I've used LL Keyboard hooks myself, but only in situations where `RegisterHotkey` was not an option.

Comment: On the desktop that's certainly an issue and an excellent point.  Embedded devices almost always are running one or two core applications and typically serve a single purpose, so all keyboard input is most likely to be targeted at your application anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms961355.aspx) function defined in coredll. On the devbuzz forum you can find a post called: [code for c# hotkey register/unregister](http://forums.devbuzz.com/tm.asp?m=38708&p=1&tmode=1) which shows an implementation

Another method is to run a separate thread and call [GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms929204.aspx) in a loop with an acceptable Sleep time. `GetAsyncKeyState` should be independent of keyboard focus.

Comment: Also tried this, but it didn't work when the app runs in background.

Comment: `GetAsyncKeyState` is a dubious choice. For example it can't see if multiple keys of a combination were pressed at the same time which leads to accidental triggers. And at least on desktop windows it has additional problems, for example the code checking the hotkey won't be recognized as a place where the application can steal focus from the current foreground program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegisterHotKey function

Note: This API is part of the complete Windows CE OS package as provided by Microsoft. The functionality of a particular platform is determined by the original equipment manufacturer (OEM) and some devices may not support this API.